# Create Debian Package with new rsyslog.d file / Restart rsyslog

Tags: debian, packaging, post-install

I have a file package.init that is placed in /etc/init.d/. Having this file and building with "dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc" dh_installinit creates the postinst file

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/package" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/package.conf" ]; then
        if [ ! -e "/etc/init/package.conf" ]; then
                update-rc.d package defaults >/dev/null
        fi
        invoke-rc.d package start || exit $?
fi
# End automatically added section
```

Also, I have an rsyslogd file that needs to be places in /etc/rsyslog.d. I managed to put the new file in the directory, but for rsyslogd to get the new configuration it needs to restart. So, I thought of creating the postinst file

```
service rsyslog restart
```

If I add this file, then the former postinst file gets overridden completely, and all it contains is "service rsyslog restart"

I am trying to avoid editing postinst manually. I was hopping that the contents of my postinst file would be appended to the the one created by dh_installinit, but that's not the case.

Here is my question:
How can I append another rule to the postinst that is created by dh_installinit.

Answer (score 2):

If you use debhelper, you only have to include a `#DEBHELPER#` statement in your maintainer script. It (and only it) will be replaced automatically by the generated content.

More information about this in the the [dh_installdeb man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/dh_installdeb.1.html).